# Cannot upload images using php in iss7

Tags: php, upload, windows-server-2008, file-permissions

I am having trouble uploading images to my server (iss7) the php code im using is

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "/jobs/upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $location = "/jobs/upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

    mysql_query("insert into jobs (location) values ('$location')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "File ". $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors :

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/jobs/upload/sig.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to        open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\####.co.uk\httpdocs

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php6D8A.tmp' to '/jobs/upload/sig.png' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\####.co.uk\httpdocs\content\jobs\photos.php on line 76
```

I have tried setting the permissions on the folders

```
C:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\content\
C:\WINDOWS\Temp\
```